# C - Scope of C Functions

Tags: c, scope, include, linkage

I apologize if this is a beginner's question, but after working in C for a bit, I finally would like a bit of clarification on exactly what kind of files/functions are available to a function.

I understand we can explicitly include other files with the #include macro like so:

```
#include bar.c
```

But what about files that are in the same directory? Let's say we have the following file structure:

```
src-
   |
   a.c
   b.c
```

And let's say a.c has the function "foo()" and b.c has "bar()"

Would I be able to call bar() within a.c even without explicitly including b.c in the header file?

And what about in sub-directories such as the following:

```
src-
   |
   a.c
   |
   someFolder-
             |
             b.c
```

Would I still be able to access bar() in a.c?

Basically, how exactly is the scope of functions (without including them in headers) defined?

Comment: If your compiling and linking them together, yes.

Comment: Note: `#include bar.c` is not recommended. we have header files.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Not even “not recommended,” but plain wrong. There ought to be double quotes around the `bar.c`.

Comment: @FUZxxl depends. What if the `.c` contains only declarations? The extension is not of much use, anyway. Syntax part, I agree. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The `".c"` still is the wrong extension. Use `".h"`.

Comment: @Olaf I thought _"we have header files"_ was clear enough. :)

Comment: Wow, never knew my terrible "#include" would generate so much discussion. I honestly feel educated - thanks!

This is what happens when you code in Java for awhile and you forget your basic C :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing *scope* with *linkage.*

The term *scope*  descibes if an identifier is visible to the compiler in a given context. The broadest scope known to the C language is *file scope* which means that the identifier is visible from the point it is declared to the end of the translation unit after preprocessing. You can make any identifier visible/known by declaring it, but making an identifier visible does not mean that refering to the identifier refers to the thing it refers to in another file.

The term *linkage* describes how two identifiers refer to the same thing. There are three levels of linkage: with *no linkage,* each identifier with the name refers to a different thing. With *internal linkage,* each identifier within the same translation unit refers to the same thing. With *external linkage,* each identifier in the whol program refers to the same thing. For two identifiers in two translation units to refer to the same thing, you need to declare both of them to have external linkage.

This is independent of how the declaration is obtained. There is no difference in writing `int foo()`  in a common header file to writing the same line in both source files. In either case, all identifiers refer to the same `foo()` as functions have external linkage unless explicitly declared to have internal linkage with the `static` type specifier.

It is also independent of how your source code is laid out. As long as all translation units are linked into the same binary, you can call all functions with external linkage in each translation unit.

Comment: Ah, I see now.

In my actual use case, I was going through some open-source C code and I became confused because I noticed that some functions were being called from a different file even though they weren't explicitly included. When I actually go through the Makefile, I can now see that the ".o" files are being linked together.

Thanks for the thorough explanation

Comment: @Victor3y It's a pleasure to me.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you are linking these into one binary or not.

If linking - then yes, functions can be called with implicit declaration.

Common pattern in this case is making a header(s) file with all declarations, including `*.c` files is usually not preferred, since `#include` is just textual inclusion of file contents

Answer (score 1):

`#include` (a preprocessor directive, not a macro, BTW) has a configurable list of directories it searches.
If you use the `#include "something.h"` form (as compared to the angle bracket form for including system headers), the first directory in the list is the directory of the including file.

Although `#include` does a simple textual inclusion so it is technically possible to include any text file,  `c` files are almost never included.

In C, you usually compile c files separately into object files and link them together, and what you do include is header files which consist of declarations, which represent interfaces of the other object files which your current compilation unit otherwise wouldn't see.

Check out http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/separate-compilation/ or another article on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash "/" should work in this case.

If you can include `foo.h` without problem, this means the directory (say, `C:\DIRFOO`) is predefined in the "include" directive of the compiler. So, another file (say `bar.h`) in a sub directory (say, `C:\DIRFOO\DIRBAR`) can be included via `#include <DIRBAR/bar.h>`.